# pandas str.contains is not showing any functions

Tags: pandas, string, pycharm

When trying the following example from Google:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np
import re

s1 = pandas.Series(['Mouse', 'dog', 'house and parrot', '23', np.NaN])
s1.str.<No functions available>
```

The 2nd line has only those function options:

```
print
ifn
not
par
if
ifnn
main
return
while
```

I've tried everything and can't understand why str.x functions are not available?

Comment: It's simply an issue with the code suggestion feature of your IDE. VS Code does that a lot. The list of available functions with the `str` accessor is documented here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.capitalize.html. Look at the sidebar for the list

Answer (score 0):

The functions are there. It is probably issue with the IDE that you are working. You can try this and see if it runs.

```
>>> s1.str.count("o")
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    0.0
4    NaN
dtype: float64
```